# How can I add read more click event to only open one news article?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a section on a website where news articles are posted, but each one has a "Read More" button to open up the rest of the article rather than have it all loaded at once. Here is my code below...

**HTML**

```
<h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
    <p>Visible Content</p>
    <div class="continue-article">
       <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
    <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
    <p>Visible Content</p>
    <div class="continue-article">
       <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
    <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
    <p>Visible Content</p>
    <div class="continue-article">
       <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
    <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.read-toggle').click(function(){
        if($('.continue-article').hasClass('show')){
            $('.continue-article').removeClass('show');
            $(this).children('span').text('Read More');
            $(this).children('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
        }else{
            $('.continue-article').addClass('show');
            $(this).children('span').text('Close');
            $(this).children('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.continue-article {display: none;}
.show {display: block;}
.read-toggle {font-weight: bold;}
    .read-toggle:hover {cursor: pointer;}
```

The issue I am having is that when one is clicked on they all open, when I only want that particular "Read More" that was clicked on to be visible.

How can I set it up so that only the one that has been clicked on will show and change rather than all of them?

Comment: Note: consider replacing the add and remove classes with toggle classes.

Comment: I have used toggleClass as well and still each news article opens rather than only the one I clicked on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It opens all your "Read more"s, because in JS you select all `$('.continue-article')` elements.

You have to select only preceding one.

```js
$('.read-toggle').click(function() {
    if($(this).prev('.continue-article').hasClass('show')) {
        $(this).prev('.continue-article').removeClass('show');
        $(this).children('span').text('Read More');
        $(this).children('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
        
    } else {
        $(this).prev('.continue-article').addClass('show');
        $(this).children('span').text('Close');
        $(this).children('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
        }
});
```

```css
.continue-article {display: none;}
.show {display: block;}
.read-toggle {font-weight: bold;}
    .read-toggle:hover {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
    <p>Visible Content</p>
    <div class="continue-article">
       <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
    <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
    <p>Visible Content</p>
    <div class="continue-article">
       <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
    <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Author</p>
    <p>Visible Content</p>
    <div class="continue-article">
       <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
    <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As it stands now, you select all the `.read-toggle` elements and reveal or hide all the `.continue-article`. What you need is to target corresponding `.continue-article` on `.read-toggle` click.

Better approach is to wrap your articles' content in an `article` tag and use this common parent to target the intended toggle. This way you don't depend on the order your elements are placed inside the `article` container. Only on the fact that they are inside.

```
<!-- Wrap articles in article tags  -->
    <article class="entry">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Author</p>
      <p>Visible Content</p>
      <div class="continue-article">
         <p>Hidden Content</p>
      </div>
      <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    </article>

    <article class="entry">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Author</p>
      <p>Visible Content</p>
      <div class="continue-article">
         <p>Hidden Content</p>
      </div>
      <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>      
    </article>

    <article class="entry">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Author</p>
      <p>Visible Content</p>
      <div class="continue-article">
         <p>Hidden Content</p>
      </div>
      <p class="read-toggle"><span>Read More</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    </article>
```

js:

```
$('.read-toggle').click(function(){
        var $curToggle = $(this),
            // Use the article wrapper to find intended .continue-article
            $curEntry = $curToggle.parent('.entry'),
            $curContinueArticle = $curEntry.find('.continue-article');

        if($curContinueArticle.hasClass('show')){
            $curContinueArticle.removeClass('show');
            $curToggle.children('span').text('Read More');
            $curToggle.children('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
        }else{
            $curContinueArticle.addClass('show');
            $curToggle.children('span').text('Close');
            $curToggle.children('.fa').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
        }
});
```

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NIiAQZfyzuNiU7XqfCcI?p=preview)